# FileIOPermission error in dll for report

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, report

I have tried a diverse amount of methods this is my latest method which I have tried to not fire the error but to no avail I still get the FileIOPermission error

The Full error is

**Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed**

The code I am using is the below

```
    Dim permissions As New Security.PermissionSet(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.None)
    permissions.AddPermission(New Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted))
    permissions.AddPermission(New Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution))
    permissions.AddPermission(New Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.Assertion))
    permissions.Assert()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions)

    Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.Load("ReportingServiceUtils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cca1b177d76f2036")
    Dim asm_name As Reflection.AssemblyName = asm.GetName()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain(New Security.Policy.StrongName(New Security.Permissions.StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(asm_name.GetPublicKeyToken()), asm_name.Name, asm_name.Version))
```

The Code being used in the dll is the below

```
Public Sub Add(ByVal group As String, ByVal groupCurrentPageNumber As String)
    Try
        If _GroupWithRunningMaxPageNumber.ContainsKey(group) Then
            _GroupWithRunningMaxPageNumber(group) = groupCurrentPageNumber
        Else
            If _GroupWithRunningMaxPageNumber.Count = 0 Then
                Dim fileName = "C:\Working Folder\ms-dot-net-report-viewer-group-pagenation\ReportingServiceUtils\test.xml"
                sw = New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, False)
                sw.WriteLine("<root>")
                sw.WriteLine("</root>")
                sw.Close()
                sw.Dispose()
            End If
            _GroupWithRunningMaxPageNumber.Add(group, groupCurrentPageNumber)
            sw.WriteLine("<Group  current='" & group & "' lastPage='" & CStr(groupCurrentPageNumber) & "'/>", 1, 1)
            sw.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with the below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and it was quite funny when I did.
The below 1 liner solves the problem of not being able to have file access from report.

`Dim auth As New System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission( System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `PermissionSet`

```
      var sec = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);

      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(sec);
```

You can convert from `C#` to `VB.net` easyly